# Not able to enable Development mode on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

Downloaded beta iOS 13 on iPhone X and iPhone 6s but none of the devices are working in development mode.
While Running project the Xcode gave me error[Not able to enable Development Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI2Un.png)

Using Xcode 10.1 and added Developer disk image for iOS 13

Already tried restarting Xcode, restarting the device and even restarting Mac several times but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download xcode 11 to support iOS13.

Xcode 10.1 support for iOS 12.1.

See this documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes?language=objc

Comment: Apple never restricts the usage of previous versions of OS. You can use Xcode 10.1 or 10.2 with iOS 13 developer disk image

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10.1 also supports iOS 13 devices. The only thing you need is Genuine develope disk image.

Downloaded Xcode 11 Beta and then from Xcode Beta I took  Developer disk image for iOS 13 which resolves my problem.

Path:
Xcode-Beta-> Show Package Content > developer > Platform > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport